# ContentObserver not called only in LG devices

Tags: android, contentobserver, appwidgetprovider, lg

I'm programming a widget that has to update itself each time I receive a missed call. For this, in the onEnabled method of the AppWidgetProvider class, I register a ContentObserver. The code is the following:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context){
    this.mcco = new MissedCallsContentObserver(context);
    context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, this.mcco);
}
```

The code for the class MissedCallsContentObserver is the following:

```
package bembibre.coolstar.windowsmobilewidget.backend;

import bembibre.coolstar.windowsmobilewidget.backend.textproviders.CallsProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.ContentObserver;

public class MissedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    Context context;

    public MissedCallsContentObserver(Context context)
    {
        super(null);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        new CallsProvider(this.context).setData();
    }
}
```

The method onChange is called automatically each time a missed call is received by the phone. This works in a lot of devices in which I have tested it. But I also have tested it on an LG L5. This is the only device in which it doesn't work. Why? ContentObservers are not the same in a Samgung device that in an LG device? In the LG, the method onChange never gets called.
I also would like to ask a question about my eclipse debugger. With my Samsung phone it works well, but with a Sony Xperia and the LG mentioned before, it disconnects when it wants. Withouth doing nothing, the debugger disconnects suddenly. My USB wire is perfect. Also my computer and phone's USB ports. Why debugger disconnects? No exception nor error message is thrown in the logcat. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Samsung and LG heavily modify the framework code, did  you check for any LG bug reports for this issue ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I haven't found nothing. And ContentObserver is a very basic Android mechanism. I don't understand how manufacturers can change that. This would mean that in LG phones a lot of applications won't work, such as mine. Lots of applications need ContentObservers.

Comment: The cause of my problem could be that I'm calling the ContentObserver constructor passing null to it instead of a Handler instance? It is the only weird thing I see in my code.

Comment: The contentobserver is decoupled from the data, it's the contentprovider that call notifychange on any contentresolver (upon observers are registered), LG might have modified the provider to not send notoifychange calls, thus you're not receiving anything in your contentobserver. (seens strange though)

Comment: Have you launched the app at least once? Implicit intents are not received by applications that have never been launched.

Comment: I think this was my problem. Below, I answered myself. My application worked when I moved the `ContentObserver`s from the `AppWidgetProvider` to an sticky `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

All my `ContentObserver`s were registered and unregistered inside the class `AppWidgetProvider`. I read that this is not safe and for example in some LG phones it seems it does not work. What I made is an sticky `Service` (in the end of the overriden method `onStartCommand()` you have to return the constant `START_STICKY`). Then, inside the service, I register the `ContentObserver`s and now it works in all phones. It seems that an sticky service exists forever. If not, my application will stop working unless I create the service again.

When the service is created, I register the `ContentObserver`s, and when it is destroyed, I unregister them. It seems that is dangerous to forget to unregister a `ContentObserver` when you will no longer use it.